# Check if a String only contains digits and the digits are not the same using REGEX?

Tags: java, regex

```
111111111 - Invalid
A121278237 - Invalid
7777777777 - Invalid

121263263 - Valid
111111112 - Valid
```

Comment: Then why the "using regex" restriction?

Comment: Is it now a social networking site that you gotta make a pep talk?

Comment: As much as I love regex, it's not the tool for the job here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
^([0-9])(?!\1+$)[0-9]+$
```

should work. It needs a string of at least two digits to match successfully.

Explanation:

1. Match a digit and capture it into backreference #1: `([0-9])`
2. Assert that it's impossible to match a string of any length (>1) of the same digit that was just matched, followed by the end of the string: `(?!\1+$)`
3. Then match any string of digits until the end of the string: `[0-9]+$`

EDIT: Of course, in Java you need to escape the backslash inside a string (`"\\"`).

Comment: "11".matches("^([0-9])(?!\1+$)[0-9]+$"); This returns true!

Comment: "assumes a string of at least two digits" -> "assumes a string with length of 2 or more"? I mean the regex seems to work correctly for all such strings; e.g. "A1" -> false.

Comment: @Milli. Curious - on my machine `"11".matches("^([0-9])(?!\\1+$)[0-9]+$")` is false! Java 1.6.0_15.

Comment: I used one '\' in the regex as how Tim specified. I should have noticed that. Thanks a bunch Jonik. And a warm thanks to Tim.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't even notice that. IntelliJ IDEA fixed it for me automatically when pasting in the regex for testing :)

Answer (score 2):

1. take a [0-9] regex and throw away strings that not only contain digits.
2. take the first character, and use it as a regex [C]+ to see if the string contains any other digits.

Comment: For production code I might well prefer this approach: do the check in separate steps using very simple regular expressions. This way the code would be more readily understood by other people on the team. So +1 for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Tim's answer, you eliminate the requirement of "at least two digits" by adding an or clause.

```
^([0-9])(?!\1+$)[0-9]+$|^[0-9]$
```

For example:

```
String regex = "^([0-9])(?!\\1+$)[0-9]+$|^[0-9]$";
boolean a = "12".matches(regex);
System.out.println("a: " + a);
boolean b = "11".matches(regex);
System.out.println("b: " + b);
boolean c = "1".matches(regex);
System.out.println("c: " + c);
```

returns

```
a: true
b: false
c: true
```